# Why could a monitor go into power save mode during bootup?

Tags: windows, boot, graphics-card, display

I have a weird problem: Since last night, when I boot my 2012-vintage custom-built Windows 7 PC with an Geforce GTX 660 video cards (with separate power connector), the monitor will *usually* permanently drop into power save mode mid way through the boot process, with no way to revive it.  However, this never happened before last night and only happens inconsistently (*rarely* it will come up immediately after a system restore).  Here are the precise sequence of symptoms:

1. I boot my PC
2. BIOS displays video normally
3. Windows starts to boot
4. While the Windows logo screen is displayed, the video will cut out after maybe 30 seconds, and the display will go to sleep.  No mouse or keyboard activity brings it back.  It seems to cut out at a specific point during the boot process.  The login screen is not displayed.
5. Hard disk (SSD) activity will continue for maybe 15-30 more seconds, then stop.
6. Nothing happens if I wait 20+ minutes.
7. If I reset the PC, Windows will prompt to enter the boot repair mode.  That won't help, but *rarely* I can manage a single good boot after restoring to a restore point or restoring from an system image backup.
8. When boot recovery wants to run, I can't seem to F8 into safe mode to see if that helps.

I pulled the video card this morning, and managed to get a good boot (using onboard video).  I haven't done any experimenting to see if it can boot repeatedly now, since I wanted to copy my files off to my NAS (just in case) and that didn't finish before I had to go to work.

What could be the root cause?  If it's a hardware issue, it's weird that the machine could successfully boot with video *sometimes* after Windows repair work.  If it's a software/Windows issue, it's weird that a full system image restore did not fix it.

Is there anything I can do to get more detail about what exact stage in the boot process that it's having issues?  The Windows logo tells me little to nothing.

Comment: Even though you say it is an intermittent issue, the fact that you got a good boot using onboard video makes me think that it is a problem with your video card.

As much as a pain as it would be, can you try putting that video card in another computer, and try booting with that?  If you get the same issue, then I would say that is your answer.

However, you might try your monitor with another computer, just in case.

Comment: Definitely not weird that it sometimes boots. This is common with failing hardware.

Comment: @Service Manager: I haven't tried rebooting after pulling the video card, so I don't know if that really fixed it.  It booted fine a few times with the video card as well.

Comment: Pulling the video card and using onboard video seems to have worked around the issue.

Comment: I ended up replacing my video card with a newer one that performs better while using less power.  This appears to have solved the issue for me.